# Download PDF instead open in browser

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
if ( '13137' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
    location = '<?php echo $file['url']; ?>';
}}, false );
```

I need to that download the pdf instead opening on browser

I found only aswer that shows how to do that with , not on javascript

Comment: Are you generating PHP from JavaScript? That does not seem safe

Comment: @mousetail — It's the other way around

Comment: @mousetail i didnt know about that, whats the other way to do that? Thank you